# How to host WCF Service Publicly in VS 2013

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, windows-phone-8.1

How do I host WCF Service publicly or with Public IP, because I have added this service using service reference in Windows Phone 8.1 App, Now, I want to test it on device with any network. Somebody pointed me the option of "Windows Azure". Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Azure or Amazon Web Services are the most popular, but you can also use any web hosting company that can host WCF/ASP.NET Sites.

Regarding Azure, After installed the Microsoft Azure SDK, you can create a 'cloud project' in Visual Studio, where you can configure your WCF/REST service to be deployed into Azure as a cloud service, which will have a public IP & hostname.

[How to create & deploy cloud services in Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/)

Comment: ohh thanks brother, Once hosted, then shall I be able to run windows phone 8.1 app on physical device?

Comment: yes, you will be able to access the hosted service from anywhere.